# Using Google Play Games Services for Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-play-games

I would like to use https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer for a Flutter app I am writing. How would I do that with Dart/Flutter?

Comment: It needs a plugin and I didn't find one. Someone should write it I think :)

Comment: I think it would be better if you try posting this request [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues), this will let them know that developers are in need of a guide for GPGS.

Comment: Not sure issues are a good support platform, but I posted it there .. I will report back what happens.

Answer (score 2):

*Update 12/26:*

It seems that https://pub.dev/packages/play_games lacks iOS support

---

So for a plugin with iOS support, you can take a look at:

- https://pub.dev/packages/games_services

or

- https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis

  - this is more official, since it is by the Dart.dev team, but probably not as convenient to setup since it is done through the Web/REST API:
  - https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/blob/master/generated/googleapis/lib/games/v1.dart
  - https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api

---

For general docs, please see https://developers.google.com/games/services

Comment: play-games - is not a full-fledged plugin, it lacks an implementation for ios

Comment: I'd try games_services

Comment: After all these years what's the best option?